# Keeping responsive background images consistent across devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

As a relative beginner, I seem to be struggling to find the right balance between creating media queries based on content rather than specific devices.

I'm wrestling at the moment with a landing page that has a css background image covering the entire viewport. In order to ensure the image remains consistent (i.e.  no cropping) across all mobile devices, I started writing device-based media queries that each load different versions of the image. By the time I'd created them for four different iPhones (portrait and landscape) alarm bells were going off.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do or should I just accept that the image is going to look different from device to device?

All help gratefully received.

Steve

Comment: have you tried to specify a background-size, e.g to `cover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sixrevisions.com/css/responsive-background-image/

```
body {
  background: url(background-photo.jpg) center center cover no-repeat fixed;
}
```

This should look relatively good across all devices.

Comment: Thank you, Tania. This is the approach I've been using, only without 'fixed'. I'm still finding that parts of the image go missing at the edges though as the viewport is resized. The background image is based on a headshot emerging from the right-hand, so trying to fix it with extra space isn't really an option.